# Php unit testing pass config file from command

Tags: php, unit-testing, integration-testing

I am implementing some Integration tests by using unit testing. I am using the `setUp()` method to set a config file. My config file consists of some `Api keys` `API secret` etc. This is working good.

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->_pipeline = new Pipline($this);
    $this->_pipeline->setConfig(\Api\Models\ConfigModel::createFromFile(__DIR__ . '/test/integration/assets/config'));
    $users = $this->_pipeline->users->listUsers();
    $this->_userId = $users->result->data[0]->user_id;

    parent::setUp(); 
}
```

This method is working good in this way.

**Problem**
But I want to pass the config file from command. Currently i am using this command

> php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c ./test/integration/phpunit.xml

Is there a way i can pass this from command something like this

> php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c ./test/integration/phpunit.xml
>   -c2 /test/integration/assets/config

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could pick it up from an env variable defined, these can also be set in your phpunit.xml ( `<env name="foo" value="bar"/>` )

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass the name as an argument to php:

```
php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c ./test/integration/phpunit.xml -- /test/integration/assets/config
```

You can access the arguments via [`$argc`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php); `$argv[0]` is the name of the script, so your config file name will be in `$argv[1]`.

e.g.

```
E:\>php -r "echo \"$argc\n\"; print_r($argv);" -- "hello world!"
2
Array
(
    [0] => -
    [1] => hello world!
)
```